# "Out do each other" what does this mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I would like to ask thing a few about the abovementioned term.

At Reddit, there is a JLL site which I am participating.

About 2 hours ago from my posting here, a woman jumped in exclaiming "Why is the Japanese language learning community so elitist?"?

And here is the line.

> I’m just gonna call it out. Japanese language learning circles are extremely elitist, if not downright hostile. I literally do not see such hostility in Spanish, French, Russian, Italian, German, ANY other language learning communities. It’s only with Japanese. You can even see it in this sub, which is why I don’t do much more than lurk here.

> It’s like foreigners are trying to **out do** **each other** with how serious they are about learning Japanese. So many people are out here trying to prove they aren’t one of those weebs who want to learn Japanese because of anime or manga.

Sorry that my question is so simple in comparison with the length.

What does the bold part, "out do" mean here?

Comment: It's a misspelling, but you can search for dictionary definitions of "outdo" and then let us know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Juhasz Someone could even search for "out do" and get the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Outdo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/outdo) means "to be, or do something, better than someone else"; for example,

"He always tries to outdo everybody else in the class."

[Cambridge Dictionary]